# Simple way for linking boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost

I'd like to use (in Linux Debian Squeeze g++4.4) separately-compiled Boost (1.54.0) libraries:

- Boost.Chrono
- Boost.Context
- Boost.Filesystem
- Boost.GraphParallel
- Boost.IOStreams
- Boost.Locale
- Boost.MPI
- Boost.ProgramOptions
- Boost.Python
- Boost.Regex
- Boost.Serialization
- Boost.Signals
- Boost.System
- Boost.Thread
- Boost.Timer
- Boost.Wave

In order to do this, according to [Easy Build and Install](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html), I typed in terminal

```
$ cd path/to/boost_1_54_0
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=~/boost
$ ./b2 install
```

As a result two folders `include` and `lib` were created in `~/boost`. In `~/boost/lib` there are files:

```
libboost_name.a
libboost_name.so
libboost_name.so.1.54.0
```

for each boost library.

Then I include some library (for example regex) in my test.cpp file:

```
#include<boost/regex.hpp>   //may be also chrono, filesystem or whatever
```

I tell the compiler to search for regex library in ~/boost/lib

```
$ g++ -I path/to/boost_1_54_0 test.cpp -o test -L~/boost/lib -lboost_regex
```

But this results in compilation error:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is wrong? There are no `stage` folder in my `~/boost`, nor antything like `libboost_regex-gcc34-mt-d-1_36.a` mentioned in [Easy Build and Install](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html). Is this the reson?

Here is the content of test.cpp

```
//I need a general solution/idea that works for any of these libraries
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
//#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
//#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
//#include<boost/some-other-separately-compiled-library>

int main()
{
}
```

**Is there a simple way for linking boost libraries that works for all of the Boost libraries that must be built separately?**

Comment: I don't see how you're invoking linker.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, I've just edited the question

Comment: Try to link `boost_system` too.

Comment: Please post a complete and reproducible example. I do not thing Boost_Regex would pull in Boost_System if you just include the one top-level header; see my answer below.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, for regex it works even like this: `g++ -I /usr/include/boost_1_54_0 test.cpp -o test`. But this is not the case with other libraries.

Comment: Disagree--It does not build if I omit `-lboost_regex`; if I add it the resulting executable does have a dependency on it per `ldd`.  Anyway, your question is still underspecified, we told you what we need and there isn't much more I can do for you now with limited info you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is not right with your Boost setup. Any particular library within Boost should correctly resolve as needed.

On a Debian / Ubuntu system, with headers and libraries in standard places and using Boost as shipped, I can just invoke `g++` with a single `-lfoo`:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ -o boost_re_ex boost_regex_credit_card_ex.cpp -lboost_regex
edd@max:/tmp$ ./boost_re_ex 
validate_card_format("0000111122223333") returned 0
validate_card_format("0000 1111 2222 3333") returned 1
validate_card_format("0000-1111-2222-3333") returned 1
validate_card_format("000-1111-2222-3333") returned 0
machine_readable_card_number("0000111122223333") returned 0000111122223333
machine_readable_card_number("0000 1111 2222 3333") returned 0000111122223333
machine_readable_card_number("0000-1111-2222-3333") returned 0000111122223333
machine_readable_card_number("000-1111-2222-3333") returned 000111122223333
human_readable_card_number("0000111122223333") returned 0000-1111-2222-3333
human_readable_card_number("0000 1111 2222 3333") returned 0000-1111-2222-3333
human_readable_card_number("0000-1111-2222-3333") returned 0000-1111-2222-3333
human_readable_card_number("000-1111-2222-3333") returned 000-1111-2222-3333
edd@max:/tmp$
```

This use [the Boost 'credit card' example file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/example/snippets/credit_card_example.cpp)  straight from their website.

Comment: I also use Debian. This credit card example compiles for me but gives runtime error: `boost_re_ex: /usr/include/boost_1_54_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:646: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Abort trap`

Comment: Can you try the _packaged versions_ rather than your own build?

Comment: You mean install boost through `apt-get`? No, because I need boost 1.54.0 and `apt-get` works for 1.42.

Comment: You are in a pickly as you insist on an ancient Debian version yet desire a brandnew Boost.  What I have done in the past (when I was *really* sure I needed it) was to rebuild the newest Debian package from source. Debian 'sid' aka 'unstable' has 1.54.  But we digress: I still think your local build is at fault.

Comment: You are right. I did not removed my old packaged boost 1.42. After `apt-get remove libboost1.42-dev` I can use boost as in your answer. Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Can't give an exact answer because I don't know which `boost` lib depends on which, but here's the thing: with the default Linux linker (don't know what's it called, ld?) you have to be very careful with the order in which you feed libs to a linker (order of your `-l` flags). You have to specify a depending library first and then a dependent library, in that order. So if your application uses library `a` and `a` depends on `b`, the order is:

`-la -lb`,

not the other way around. Otherwise when linker encounters a new input library that's isn't yet required by any previously linked code, it will optimize symbols from this new "unneccessary" library away.

Bottom line - find out the order of dependence between your `boost` libraries.

Comment: Try ldd on `libboost_regex.so.1.*`, it has no dependencies on other Boost libraries.